# How do I fix this multidimensional array?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, multidimensional-array

So I need to make a program that displays the monthly sales and totals of three different areas of a company when I click a button. I've added this code, but can't seem to get it right. Can someone advise me on how to fix it. Also, my headings "province, Percentage, Contribution etc" does not display in the list box when the form is loaded.

So basically the values in my .txt files are as follows:

1,Kwazulu Natal,44,120000
1,Gauteng,33,900000
1,Western Cape,23,65000
2,Kwazulu Natal,56,190000
2,Gauteng,25,85000
2,Western Cape,19,64000
3,Kwazulu Natal,54,175000
3,Gauteng,25,80000
3,Western Cape,21,71000
4,Kwazulu Natal,55,188000
4,Gauteng,25,83000
4,Western Cape,20,67000
5,Kwazulu Natal,46,125000
5,Gauteng,31,87000
5,Western Cape,23,65000
6,Kwazulu Natal,53,163000
6,Gauteng,26,80000
6,Western Cape,21,64000

Now they are supposed to show underneath their headings per month (1 - 6). When I run my code, they do not show headings, just the names of the places. It does not give errors

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class FormMain

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        resultsBox.Items.Clear()
        resultsBox.Columns.Add("Province", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Center)
        resultsBox.Columns.Add("Percentage", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Center)
        resultsBox.Columns.Add("Contribution", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Center)
        resultsBox.Columns.Add("Total Cost", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Center)
    End Sub

    Private Sub ExitBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExitBtn.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ShowResultsBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ShowResultsBtn.Click

        Dim salesReport As String = MonthlyCBox.Text
        Dim filereader As New StreamReader("C:\Users\HP Notebook 15\Desktop\main.txt")
        Dim details As Array
        Dim provinceFound As String = " "
        Dim percentageContribute As Integer = 0
        Dim monthlySales As Integer = 0
        Dim totalvalue As Integer = 0

        While filereader.EndOfStream = False
            details = filereader.ReadLine().Split(",")
            Dim province As String = details(1)
            Dim percentage As Decimal = details(2)
            Dim monthlyammount As String = details(3)
            Dim totalamm As String = details(3)
            If details(0) = salesReport Then
                resultsBox.Items.Add(New ListViewItem({province, percentage, FormatCurrency(monthlyammount), FormatCurrency(totalamm)}))
            End If
        End While

    End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: If you could also Consider turning option strict On and giving all the errors it causes it would be marvellous!

Comment: What multidimensional array? There isn't one anywhere in that code. That's a good thing, but you might provide a title that actually relates to the question. If your issue is really populating a `ListView` then the title should reflect that.

Comment: You should not be adding the columns to your `ListView` in code. Do it in the designer. Either way, if you can't see the columns then it's probably because you haven't set the `View` property to `Details`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using ListView, Not List Box. If so, please add
`resultsBox.View = View.Details`, in load event. That should visible the header text.